# OpenGL FBO renderbuffer or texture attatchment

Tags: opengl

In what cases would I want to have a renderbuffer attachment in an OpenGL FBO, instead of a texture attachment, besides for the default framebuffer? As, a texture attachment seems far more versatile.

Comment: I've been wondering about this for a long time. My guess is that there existed a base of legacy programs based on PBuffer, and some people were unwilling to adapt to a different concept (i.e. write to texture instead of write to PBuffer and copy), so the exact PBuffer functionality was re-implemented on top of FBO to encourage them to use FBO. I really can't think of any other reason, because renderbuffer attachments are not useful at all (trying hard to avoid saying "retarded"). There is no immediately obvious reason why rendering to texture should be any slower (or any different).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Textures provide more features to you (sampling!, formats variety) and hence are more likely subject to performance loss.

The answer is simple: use *Textures* wherever you have to sample from the surface (no alternatives).

Use *Render buffers* wherever you don't need to sample. The driver may or may not decide to store your pixel data more effectively based on your expressed intention of not doing sampling.
You can use GL blitting afterwards to do something with the result.

Comment: Finally, a good, straight answer to this simple question. Thanks. It seems many having nothing but wishy-washy comments on this topic (in other words -- they don't know).

Comment: What does *sample from the surface* mean? Can you give more concrete examples where one needs to sample and when not?

Comment: @bluenote10 by "sampling" I mean querying particular values of the texture in a shader. See "Texture lookup functions" at https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29 for more info. For example, if you need to blur something, your shader will typically sample an area of pixels and weight them, so you need a texture source. In the other scenario, if you just want to draw something with the depth testing, you may use a depth render buffer.

Comment: @kvark can you contrast that with fetching a texel at a given point?  For instance, can renderbuffers be used for deferred shading passes where the resolving shader only needs to access a specific texel at a specific point without interpolation?

Comment: @Jherico you can't fetch a texel from a render buffer, only from textures.

Comment: Totally agree. Use Renderbuffer you can fetch it to cpu with `glReadPixels`, while use Texture you can use it in following rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the question to OpenGL|ES, another reason to use RenderBuffers instead of textures is also that textures may not be supported in some configurations and prevent you from building a valid FBO. I specifically think about **depth** textures, which are not natively supported on some hardware, for instance nVidia Tegra 2/3.